# Having each User have their own data - Flutter - Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm adding data to FireStore like this :

```
onPressed: () async {
  // signInAnonymously();
  UserCredential userCredential =
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
  addReminderToFirebase();
  validateForm();
},
```

.

```
Future<DocumentReference> addReminderToFirebase() {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Reminders')
      .add(<String, dynamic>{
    'text': "Remember to do Laundry",
    'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
    'userId': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
  });
}
```

Currently I have documents everyone has access to it's all mixed up

How do I make each user have their own data ? Not accessible by anyone else ?

Answer (score 1):

You should fetch the data of the specific user by using their `userId`.

You can fetch current user data by using the following snippet.

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Reminders')
        .where('userId', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
```

Comment: How would I implement it in my code ? I don't see where

Comment: I don't understand how I then add my data ^^? I'd like to upVote but I need 10 more points

Comment: You should add this code where you are displaying reminders. In this way, only the reminders of a currently logged user will be fetched and displayed.

Comment: ok thank you - how do I grab a value from this document ?

Comment: I'd like to upvote your answer but it doesn't allow me to

Comment: You can get the document id by `ref.id` where **ref** is the document you received.

Comment: No worries) you can still accept my answer by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) guide

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a field `userId` which can be used to get creator of that reminder. You can check if the user requesting the reminder is the same person i.e. the UID of requester is same as the `userId` field. Try these security rules:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Reminders/{reminderId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Then to fetch reminders of a single user you can use [queries](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querying)

```
var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser
if (currentUser) {
 remindersCollection.where("userId", "==", currentUser.uid)
}
```